# Python - Pandas, расчет разницы времени

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Всем привет! Есть таблица df, содержащая данные в формате "час:мин" и
для которой нужно рассчитать разницу между строками в минутах.
Текущий скрипт должен вернуть целое значение 65 (01:15 - 00:10), но пока он дает ошибку, что идет несоответствие форматов...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['00:10','01:15','02:45','04:00']})

corr1=str(df.iloc[0,:])
corr2=str(df.iloc[1,:])
res1 = datetime.strptime(corr1,'%H:%M')
res2 = datetime.strptime(corr2,'%H:%M')
diff=res2-res1

print(diff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы бы посмотрели, что у вас в `corr1` и `corr2`. Там такая строка (на примере `corr1`):

```
'Time    00:10\nName: 0, dtype: object'
```

Нельзя просто брать и всё подряд в `str` преобразовывать. Вот так будет работать (значение ячейки уже строка, просто нужно его правильно взять):

```py
corr1=df.iloc[0,0]
corr2=df.iloc[1,0]
```

Результат после такого исправления:

```
1:05:00
```

Comment: А как 1:05:00 преобразовать в 65? И почему не срабатывает вариант  corr1=df.iloc[0,:]?

Comment: @leonardik А вы сами-то пытались найти ответ? Это же элементарный пример, в десятках мест описанный: diff.total_seconds()/60

Comment: @leonardik `df.iloc[0,:]` возвращает `Series`, а не скаляр. Даже в случае, если колонка одна. Как вариант можно так: `df.iloc[0,:].values[0]`